Choosing the threshold in DeepFace
Is there any study that shows how the default thresholds were chosen for the models present in DeepFace?
def find_threshold(model_name: str, distance_metric: str) -> float:
    base_threshold = {"cosine": 0.40, "euclidean": 0.55, "euclidean_l2": 0.75}

    thresholds = {
        # "VGG-Face": {"cosine": 0.40, "euclidean": 0.60, "euclidean_l2": 0.86}, # 2622d
        "VGG-Face": {
            "cosine": 0.68,
            "euclidean": 1.17,
            "euclidean_l2": 1.17,
        },  # 4096d - tuned with LFW
        "Facenet": {"cosine": 0.40, "euclidean": 10, "euclidean_l2": 0.80},
        "Facenet512": {"cosine": 0.30, "euclidean": 23.56, "euclidean_l2": 1.04},
        "ArcFace": {"cosine": 0.68, "euclidean": 4.15, "euclidean_l2": 1.13},
        "Dlib": {"cosine": 0.07, "euclidean": 0.6, "euclidean_l2": 0.4},
        "SFace": {"cosine": 0.593, "euclidean": 10.734, "euclidean_l2": 1.055},
        "OpenFace": {"cosine": 0.10, "euclidean": 0.55, "euclidean_l2": 0.55},
        "DeepFace": {"cosine": 0.23, "euclidean": 64, "euclidean_l2": 0.64},
        "DeepID": {"cosine": 0.015, "euclidean": 45, "euclidean_l2": 0.17},
        "GhostFaceNet": {"cosine": 0.65, "euclidean": 35.71, "euclidean_l2": 1.10},
    }

    threshold = thresholds.get(model_name, base_threshold).get(distance_metric, 0.4)

    return threshold

How to choose an ideal value in each scenario? Is it something completely empirical?
I was testing the models, and in some cases, the detection produced incorrect recognitions.

It is described in this tutorial: https://sefiks.com/2020/05/22/fine-tuning-the-threshold-in-face-recognition/

From my own experience: yes, it is completely empirical. Look at, for example, the values of cosine similarity for the different models. The same mathematics but variety of thresholds.

Long story short, same person pairs and different persons pairs are fed to models to get embeddings, then distance between found embeddings found. Thereafter, the best split point found for same person and different person classes.
